# Сколько записей было сделано за определенное время mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть таблица с тремя полями id, время создания записи(создается автоматом mysql) и еще одно поле с данными пользователя. Как можно узнать сколько записей было сделано за за определенное время.

Comment: Уточните, что именно вызывает проблемы. Запрос - простейший.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста скинуть сам запрос если он простой?

Comment: тут ведь не сервис домашних заданий, тут помогают решить, а не решают за вас. Вот и расскажите, чего вам удалось добиться в решении этой задачи и какие проблемы при этом возникли.